# can i load 12.04 into a completely formatted pc via a usb stick?

Tags: 12.04, usb

when my son was given a pc that needed its original windows disc to boot again, i had an ubuntu 9.04 disc so we loaded that in instead, removing windows in the process. however, since this was an older version of ubuntu, there was a lot he couldn't use or do, so i sent off for a 12.04 usb stick. we are trying to load this into his computer but can't get things running as they should - he has to have the old disc in to start the pc in the first place. Is there a way we can remove everything and just turn on the pc with new usb inserted and things will load in fresh from there?

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert the usb with the computer off. Then turn it on and enter the BIOS as soon as possible at the start up (sometimes pressing the F8 or Esc or F12, depending on your machine, it usually tells you what key to press at the splash screen (when the mainboard/processor manufacturer logo appears). Once inside the BIOS go to the boot device priority and tell it to boot from the USB stick. In some cases the USB stick does not appear as Removable Device but appears as Hard Disk Drive, double check just in case. Save and Exit. Then your machine should boot from the USB. Once in Live Ubuntu, install the OS and choose the option to use the whole HDD (not to upgrade/use along other prior OS).

Comment: thanks for your reply - seems we're unable to format at the moment, and we're busy trying to do that first. otherwise all we get up is the screen  (after selecting language) that asks where we're booting form and won't accept anything other than the disc. busy right now but if i can format it i'll run the process as you've suggested. thanks again for your time.

Comment: What screen are you talking about? BIOS screen? or Ubuntu Start Up screen?